# Google script to split comma separated values into rows

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a google script to create a row for each comma separated value and also create all possible permutations if there is more than one column that contains comma separated values. For example:

**My Table:**
[image]
**What I need is:**
[image]

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're looking for a script ready, search the interwebs, if you want someone to script for you, hire a programmer, if you're stuck in some part of the code, tried a lot and can't make it work, show a snippert to us and we'll help in that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then it would be the logic you have to write to get that. You have to copy the cell values to two different arrays.

```
Function testFunc()
{

   Get the values to arrays.
   for loop for first array(for a,b values(arrayA)){
   for each value in the arrayA loop through arrayB(123) and add them in    the cells by increasing the row number eachtime.
   }
}
```

You could use `str.split(',');` function to spil the comma separated values to arrays.

Hope that helps!